# Создание двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Как создать двумерный динамический массив так, чтобы можно было получать доступ как к статическому `Array[a][b]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это тема здесь как-то уже поднималась. Но напишу еще раз. Создать массив int 10x20
Способ 1

```
const int x = 10, y = 20;
int ** array = (int**) malloc (sizeof (int*) * x);
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  array [i] = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int)*y);
}
```

Обращаться к элементам такого массива можно array[m][n]

Как при любом динамическом выделении памяти, ее нужно вовремя освобождать. Как это сделать, подумайте сами.

Способ 2.

```
int * array = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int)*x*y);
```

Но обращаться к его элементy [m][n] можно только так:

```
int a = *(array + y*m + n);
```

Comment: неплохо) спасибо )

Comment: Кстати, массивы небольшого размера, который неизвестен во время компиляции, можно создавать и на стеке. Для этого нужно заменить malloc на alloca. И освобождать его не нужно. При возврате из функции он сам удалится.

Comment: угу. тоже правильно.

Answer (score 2):

И все же, для того, чтобы потом ссылаться на этот вопрос как на дубликат, я немного допишу.

Итак, вариант - который нужен в общем-то только для совместимости с объявлением обычного массива `type array[Rows][Cols]` -

```
type * array = new type[Rows*Cols];            // C++
type * array = malloc(sizeof(type)*Rows*Cols); // C
```

Освобождение памяти простейшее -

```
delete[] array;  // C++
free(array);     // C
```

Плюс: совместимость по схеме размещения в памяти с обычным массивом. Минус: обращение `array[r][c]` не работает - только `array[r*Cols+c]` или `*(array+r*Cols+c)`.

Варианты, допускающие обращение `array[r][c]` - но сразу же предупреждение: несовместимы с размещением в памяти обычного массива. Легкий минус всех их - двойное косвенное обращение.

Вариант простейший.

```
// C++
type ** array = new type*[Rows];
for(size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) array[i] = new type[Cols];

....
 
for(size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) delete[] array[i];
delete[] array;

// C
type ** array = malloc(sizeof(type*)*Rows);
for(size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) array[i] = malloc(sizeof(type)*Cols);

....
 
for(size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) free(array[i]);
free(array);
```

Обращение к элементам массива - `array[r][c]`.

Если немного подумать, то в варианте для С, где нет никаких конструкторов-деструкторов, можно упростить освобождение памяти:

```
// C
type ** array = malloc(Rows*(sizeof(type*) + sizeof(type)*Cols));
for(size_t i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) array[i] = 
    ((unsigned char*)array +sizeof(type*)*Rows+i*sizeof(type)*Cols);

....
 
free(array);
```

Плюс один - очистка памяти в одно касание. Минусы - возможные проблемы выравнивания, возможная проблема strict aliasing. Как мне кажется, *реально* проявляться не должны, но тем не менее буду признателен тем, кто покажет, как *строго* избавиться от проблем при сохранении функциональности.

Впрочем... еще есть и плюс второй:

```
type * a = (type*)((unsigned char*)array +sizeof(type*)*Rows);
```

совместим с массивом `type a[Rows][Cols]` по размещению в памяти. Так что с одним и тем же массивом можно работать и так, и эдак...

Еще одна экзотика - поскольку по указателю нельзя определить размеры массива...

Вот такой вариант кода, как приведено ниже, позволяет хранить размеры массива прямо в выделенном массиве (перед указателями). Проблема в том, что при этом из функции возвращается смещенный указатель, так что цена вопроса - в том, что удалять такой массив нужно только через свою функцию. Зато при передаче не нужны никакие дополнительные параметры :)

```
T** create(int N, int M)
{
    T** arr = (T**)malloc(2*sizeof(int)+N*(sizeof(T*)+M*sizeof(T)));
    *((int*)arr)   = N;
    *((int*)arr+1) = M;
    arr = (T**)((char*)arr+2*sizeof(int));

    for(int i = N, ofs = N*sizeof(T*);
        i-->0; ofs += M*sizeof(T))
        arr[i] = (T*)((char*)arr + ofs);

    return arr;
}

void kill(T** arr)
{
    free((char*)arr-2*sizeof(int));
}

int rows(T**arr)
{
    return *(int*)((char*)arr-2*sizeof(int));
}

int cols(T**arr)
{
    return *(int*)((char*)arr-sizeof(int));
}
```

Все это относится только к C, потому что в С++ этих проблем нет - просто берем и объявляем

```
vertor<vector<type>> array(Rows,vector<type>(Cols));
```

после чего есть все - и обращение `array[i][j]`, и нужные размеры -

```
Rows == array.size()
Cols == array[0].size()
```

Нужно только следить, чтоб случайно не изменить размер какого-то из векторов...

Answer (score -1):

```
int** dynMatrix = new int* [sizeY];
for (int** matrixPtr = dynMatrix; matrixPtr < dynMatrix + sizeY; ++matrixPtr)
{
    *matrixPtr = new int[sizeX];
    for (int* linePtr = *matrixPtr; linePtr < *matrixPtr + sizeX; ++linePtr)
    {
        *linePtr = ++num;
    }

}
```

Comment: Правильное создание двумерного динамического массива

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Зачем второй ответ. Можно редактировать этот.