# Умножение матрицы на вектор Си

Tags: c, матрицы, вектор

Требуется реализовать функцию, которая умножает матрицу на вектор. Матрица - двумерный массив, вектор - одномерный. Я реализовал функции для скалярного умножения и произведения матрицы на число, вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double dot( double *x, double *y, int n )
{
    double res = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        res += x[i] * y[i];
    }
    return res;
}

void mxv( double **m,  double *v, double *res, int rows, int cols )
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        res[i] = dot(m[i], v, cols);
    }
}

int main()
{
    double m[3][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    double v[3] = {1,2,3};
    double res[3] = {0};
    mxv((double**)m, v, res, 3, 3);

    printf("%f \n", res[0]);
    printf("%f \n", res[1]);
    printf("%f \n", res[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

В результате возникает segmentation fault. Видимо, это происходит из-за неправильной передачи указателя. Уже пытался использовать следующий вариант

```
 mxv(m, v, res, 3, 3);
```

Ошибка всё равно возникает. Подскажите, что я делаю не так, как это исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что `int[Rows][Cols]` и `int**` - это принципиально разные типы, **по-разному** хранящиеся в памяти.

В первом случае - это одна непрерывная область памяти, в которой выражения типа `a[3][2]` рассчитывает сам компилятор, исходя из того, что тип `int[Rows][Cols]` - это указатель на `int[Cols]` (!), а не на `int*`.

В `int**` мы имеем массив указателей, каждый их которых указывает на какой-то массив `int`'ов.

Вот примерный набросок размещения в памяти:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще раз - самое главное - в `int[Rows][Col]` вы имеете дело не с указателями на указатели на `int`, а с указателями на `int[Cols]`. А это совершенно разные типы!

Comment: `тип int[Rows][Cols] - это указатель на int[Cols]`, следовательно тип `int[Cols]` — это указатель на `int`, следовательно тип `int[Rows][Cols]` — это указатель на (указатель на `int`), следовательно тип `int[Rows][Cols]` — это тип `int**` :)

Comment: @wololo Не запутывайте молодежь своими софизмами... :)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение! Но как всё-таки исправить код, что поменять?

Comment: Поменять представление `double m[3][3]` на динамический двумерный массив, или `void mxv( double **m, ...` на `void mxv( double m[][3], ...` См. также  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/62781/195342